# How to export table data to csv where date 'today'

Tags: mysql

I am hoping someone can help with this i am trying to export data daily from a table i.e. Columns: Title, Date, Count into a csv what would be the sql query for this?

```
SELECT 'Title', 'Date', 'Count'
UNION ALL
SELECT Title,Date,Count
FROM sales_com
INTO OUTFILE 'U:/CSV-LiveDB-Upload/sales_com/Data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

The above is what i am using to export the whole result set which works but i cant figure out how to export by today's date. Say i run this as a task each night to export the results for 'today' something down the lines of where date 'today'

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're simply running the SQL script and don't want to pass parameters in from a controlling application, you can use one of the date functions mentioned [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp).

Assuming the "Date" column is of type "DATE", using CURDATE() in your WHERE clause should work.

Your SQL script would look something like:

```
SELECT 'Title', 'Date', 'Count'
UNION ALL
SELECT Title,Date,Count
FROM sales_com
WHERE Date = CURDATE()
INTO OUTFILE 'U:/CSV-LiveDB-Upload/sales_com/Data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: Hi Thanks i am using current timestamp?

Comment: NOW() should work if you're looking for a timestamp containing both the current date and time. Take a look at the link I posted for other similar functions (w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp). Note, however, that the availability of some functions may depend on which RDBMS you're interfacing with.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Title', 'Date', 'Count'
UNION ALL
SELECT Title,Date,Count
FROM sales_com
WHERE Date >= to_date('2004/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
AND Date <= to_date('2004/12/31','yyyy/mm/dd');
INTO OUTFILE 'U:/CSV-LiveDB-Upload/sales_com/Data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```